# Spring AOP creates extra bean

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I 'm playing with Spring AOP.

Here is a simple class

```
public class CModel extends Car {
    private double torqueMeasure = 1;

    public CModel() {
        System.out.println(" C-Model constructor");        
    }
}
```

And Spring configuration is like this

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audit">
        <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.test.main..*(..))" method="firstControl"/>
            ...
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Ok now; when i add aop:config and intercepts CModel then Spring calls CModel constructor twice. It means Spring creates 2 CModel object, right ?

If I delete AOP config then Spring creates only one CModel object.

Any idea why it is like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think spring creates this bean and proxy for it. Dynamic proxy class extends base class, so it should call super() in its constructor. You can print stack trace in CModel constructor to be sure that (something like new Exception().printStackTrace()).

Answer (score 5):

Though I'm not sure, my guess is that spring first instantiates the regular class, and then makes a CGLIB proxy, which is a subclass. Note that for initialization you should use `@PostConstruct`, which is guaranteed to be used once.

To verify my hypothesis, add a breakpoint in the constructor and see when it is invoked - one of the times it should be right after the `CModel$EnhancedByCGLIB` something

Comment: I think you are correct. I actually blogged about it [recently](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html), maybe the OP will find some further details there. BTW there is even simpler method to verify this: `System.out.println(this)` - the second printed line will yield something like `CModel$EnhancedByCGLIB`.

Comment: It's documented in [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

Answer (score 3):

When Spring creates a proxy to your class, it will use CGLIB to generate a class that subclasses CModel.  The net affect is your constructor will be called twice.

Check out the Spring documentation for more detail (specifically the third bullet):
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying

As a side note, Spring will use the JDK proxying mechanism if your class implements an interface -- and the JDK proxying mechanism will not call your constructor.

Comment: Darn -- looks like I was beaten to the punch :)  Sorry for the duplicate answer.