# Java - Multiple decorators do not work

Tags: java, virtual, decorator

I'm currently experimenting with decorators. I created a Tank class and two decorators: DoubleGunTank (shoots more powerfully) and FasterTank (drives faster). Here they are:

```
public class Tank {
    public int shoot() {
        return 100;
    }

    public int drive() {
        return 10;
    }
}
public class FasterTank extends Tank {

    protected Tank fTank;

    public FasterTank(Tank tank) {
        fTank = tank;
    }

    public int drive() {
        return fTank.drive() * 2;
    }
}

public class DoubleGunTank extends Tank {

    protected Tank fTank;

    public DoubleGunTank(Tank tank) {
        fTank = tank;
    }
    public int shoot() {
        return fTank.shoot() * 2;
    }   
}
```

What I'm trying to do is decorate one tank with both double gun and the super speed. So I do it like this:

```
Tank czolg = new Tank();
czolg = new FasterTank(czolg);
czolg = new DoubleGunTank(czolg);
System.out.println("Shoot: "+czolg.shoot());
System.out.println("Drive: "+czolg.drive());
```

But the result is:

```
Shoot: 200
Drive: 10
```

It seems that only one decorator activates both methods from the DoubleGunTank class. So my question is: how do I get the tank to shoot more powerfully and drive faster at the same time?

Comment: +1, nice question for a job interview. I actually had to run it to spot the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about the Decorator pattern but `czlog.drive()` invokes `Tank.drive()` because `DoubleGunTank` does not override it.

You need to override every method in the superclass and delegate it to the contained `fTank` for this to work like you want it to.

Answer (score 5):

All your decorators need to override all decorated object's methods:

```
class FasterTank extends Tank {

    protected Tank fTank;

    public FasterTank(Tank tank) {
        fTank = tank;
    }

    public int drive() {
        return fTank.drive() * 2;
    }

    //crucial!  
    public int shoot() {
        return fTank.shoot();
    }
}

class DoubleGunTank extends Tank {

    protected Tank fTank;

    public DoubleGunTank(Tank tank) {
        fTank = tank;
    }
    public int shoot() {
        return fTank.shoot() * 2;
    }

    //crucial!  
    public int drive() {
        return fTank.drive();
    }

}
```

Here's why: when you have:

```
Tank czolg = new DoubleGunTank(new FasterTank(new Tank()));
```

and you call `czolg.drive()` it actually calls a method of `DoubleGunTank` class - which is inherited without any change from `Tank`. So instead of using decorated method of target `fTank` you are calling untouched method of `DoubleGunTank`.

Note that you can avoid such issues by using `Tank` interface - which will force you to always decorate all methods. Also if your target `Tank` class has some state or performs some operations in constructor, each decorator (inheriting from it) will have this state duplicated and will call the same code in constructor.

UPDATE (suggested by OP himself):

Alternatively you can use `abstract TankDecorator` class as below:

```
abstract class TankDecorator extends Tank {
    protected final Tank fTank;

    protected TankDecorator(Tank fTank) {
        this.fTank = fTank;
    }

    @Override
    public int shoot() {
        return fTank.shoot();
    }

    @Override
    public int drive() {
        return fTank.drive();
    }
}

class FasterTank extends TankDecorator {

    public FasterTank(Tank tank) {
        super(tank);
    }

    public int drive() {
        return fTank.drive() * 2;
    }

}

class DoubleGunTank extends TankDecorator {

    public DoubleGunTank(Tank tank) {
        super(tank);
    }
    public int shoot() {
        return fTank.shoot() * 2;
    }

}
```

---

I run across this issue when using [cglib](/questions/tagged/cglib) proxies in [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) - also exploiting decorator pattern by inheriting from my class. The base class constructor is called twice. See: [CGLIB proxy method calls constructor twice?](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81524) and [Spring AOP creates extra bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968248).

Comment: Thank you. I created a TankDecorator class which overrides all methods by default to

Comment: public method() { return fTank.method(); }. And it works perfectly.

Comment: @user1486773: +1, good point! Would you mind if I include it to my answer?

Comment: @user1486773: have a look and let me know if I got your idea wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when you're using the Decorator pattern with concrete classes, this is a common issue.  That's why i tend to decorate interfaces, however, if you need to decorate concrete classes, it's usually helpful to have a base class for this:

```
public class DecoratedTank extends Tank {
   private Tank delegate;

   public DecoratedTank(Tank delegate) {
       this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public int shoot() {
       return delegate.shoot();
   }

   @Override
   public int drive() {
       return delegate.drive();
   }
}
```

Then to do your double gun tank:

```
public class DoubleGunTank extends DecoratedTank {
    public DoubleGunTank(Tank delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public int shoot() {
        return 2 * super.shoot();
    }
}
```